# Return value from coroutine to non monobehaviour

Tags: unity, multithreading, coroutines

I have a class which is not a monobehaviour (lets call it "Generation"), and as such running CoRoutines from within are not an option.

I have a monobehaviour (lets call this "TestScript") which needs to call a function within Generation. One parameter required is a Func>.  It then calls that Func multiple times, expecting a result in the form of a double. The problem, is that it takes time to return, it needs to run across many frames, and so it kicks off some Coroutines (as this is in the monobehaviour). I set it to return a Task so that I could use Threading.SpinWait.SpinUntil and only return after the coroutines have exited, but this just hangs the main Unity thread.

Here is the function I am calling:

```
        public void AssessGeneration(Func<NeuralNet, Task<double>> assessment)
        {
            foreach (NeuralNet neuralNet in neuralNets)
            {
                neuralNet.Fitness = assessment(neuralNet).Result;
                neuralNet.fitnessAssessed = true;
            }
        }
```

So, I've tried many other things, such as moving the SpinWait into the Generation class, but still hangs. I've tried calling the function in Generation within a Task on a new thread, but when it attempts to run the coroutines it complains about not being on the main thread.

So - I have a function, in a class not inheriting from MonoBehaviour. It is called from a MonoBehaviour, and must pass in a function which takes a parameter of type NeuralNet, and returns a double. It must return a double after a coroutine has finished, but I can't be blocking the main thread.

Comment: I would suggest creating a Singleton GameObject responsible for running your coroutine, or simply pass a gameobject to the `AssessGeneration` function (the one holding the `TestScript` component, and calling the `AssessGeneration` function).

Comment: Can your generation work itself run on a different thread, rather than using coroutines at all? Or do you need access to content available only on the main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true that you can't make a method in a base class working as a coroutine.

If I understood you correctly, the `AssessGeneration` method is inside your base class, `Generation`, and you want it to be able to `yield`.

In order to do so, make its return type an `IEnumerator` instead of `void`:

```cs
public IEnumerator AssessGeneration(Func<NeuralNet, Task<double>> assessment) {}
```

then call it from your `MonoBehaviour` class `TestScript` using `StartCoroutine`, so you can use `yield` as usual inside `AssessGeneration`.

Simple example:

**Generation.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections;

public class Generation {
    public IEnumerator AssessGeneration(/*Your Parameters*/) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

**TestScript.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Generation generationInstance = new Generation();
    IEnumerator myCoroutine;

    private void Start () {     
        myCoroutine = generationInstance.AssessGeneration(/*Your Parameters*/);
        StartCoroutine(myCoroutine);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

After your comment, here's the code if you have two overloads of the same method.

**Generation.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generation {
    //This is the overload called from TestScript
    public IEnumerator AssessGeneration(/*Your parameters*/) {
        //Code before calling the second overload
        yield return AssessGeneration(/*Func parameter*/);
        //Code after completion of the second overload
    }

    //Second overload with just the Func parameter
    //If this overload is never called from outside leave it private, otherwise public
    private IEnumerator AssessGeneration(/*Func parameter*/) {
        //Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: I kind of get it, but I can't figure out how to apply that to my situation as I explained it a little simpler than it actually was. Within Generation, I have AssessGeneration with 2 different signatures - I am calling the first, which takes a number of parameters, and passes one of those (the Func<NeuralNet, Task<double>>) onto the other one. So I am calling a void function within that class, but that is the one which needs to wait for a coroutine to end.

Comment: Ok, so you have two overloads of `AssessGeneration`, I'll edit my answer to show you how it's done in this case.